# When using the checkboxes in tkinter being placed in he window using a for loop is there a way to get them to refer to different variables?

Tags: python, loops, variables, tkinter

This is my current code for my table:

```py
class Table:
    def __init__(self, root):
        headers=[' ', 'Date Added', ' ', 'Created', 'Modified', 'Project', 'Author', 'Report no', 'Vessel', 'Tag', 'Comments']
        Checks = {}
        # code for creating table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                if j == 0:
                    if i == 0:
                        self.e = Entry(root, width=5, fg='blue', font=('Arial',10,'bold'))
                    else:
                        Checks['Var'+str(i)] = 0
                        self.e=Checkbutton(root, variable=Checks['Var'+str(i)], onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

                    #self.e = Entry(root, width=5, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))
                elif j == 2 :  
                    self.e = Entry(root, width=5, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))
                elif j == 10 :  
                    self.e = Entry(root, width=100, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))
                else: 
                    self.e = Entry(root, width=10, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))

                self.e.grid(row=i+1, column=j)
                if i == 0:
                    if j == 0:
                        pass
                    else:
                        self.e.insert(END,headers[j])
                elif j == 1:
                    self.e.insert(END, Date[i-1])
                elif j == 3:
                    self.e.insert(END, DateCreated[i-1])
                elif j == 4:
                    self.e.insert(END, DateModified[i-1])
                elif j == 5:
                    self.e.insert(END, Project[i-1])
                elif j == 6:
                    self.e.insert(END, Author[i-1])
                elif j == 7:
                    self.e.insert(END, ReportNo[i-1])
                elif j == 8:
                    self.e.insert(END, Vessel[i-1])
                elif j == 9:
                    self.e.insert(END, Tag[i-1])
                elif j == 10:
                    self.e.insert(END, Comments[i-1])


total_rows = len(Date)+1 
total_columns = 11
    
root = Tk()
```

Here I have tried to use a dictionary to do this but while the dictionary seems to work, the checkboxes are still referring to the same data value(Start of the for loop). Was wondering if there is a way to get them to have sperate values so that when I change the value of one they all don't change and I can use that value elsewhere.

Comment: Try changing `Checks['Var'+str(i)]=0` to `Checks['Var'+str(i)]=IntVar()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `variable` option must be set to a tkinter variable (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc).

I would do it like this:

```
Checks[i] = IntVar(value=0)
self.e = Checkbutton(root, variable=Checks[i], onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
```

Though, it doesn't make much sense to assign it to `self.e` since you're creating many widgets but self.e can only hold one value at a time. A local variable is all you need in this loop.